# Incorrect JSON entity produced from JAX-RS response builder

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

In my JAX-RS resource I have `authenticate` method as follows that returns `Response` object.

```
public Response authenticate(@QueryParam("username") String username,
    @QueryParam("password") String password) throws JSONException, org.json.JSONException {

    JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    jsonObjBuilder.add( "auth_token", authToken );
    JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

    System.out.println("jsonObject" + jsonObj);
    return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObj).build();
}
```

The jsonObject is perfect in my print statement but my actual response built with

```
Response.status(200).entity(jsonObj).build();
```

looks like this:

```
{"auth_token":{"valueType":"STRING"}}
```

I would like the response to be look like this:

```
("auth_token":"b88c1d32-2056-4c57-926d-e8213e875b7d")
```

Comment: Where does the `authToken` variable come from and what's its type? In your snippet does not show how this value is retrieved.

Comment: The intended response is not JSON, unless the `(` and `)` is a typo.

Comment: @Tom 
authtoken is just a random string.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the point of your question. Your two examples have different values and formats. Which part do you have a problem with? The value, the format or both?

Comment: Do you have a `MessageBodyWriter` for `JsonObject`? What is `JsonObject` in this example?

Comment: Problem was solved by using json-simple.jar instead of javax.json-1.0.jar.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome/) as the JSON serialiser?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the overly complicated JsonObjectBuilder with a simple HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> jsonValues = new HashMap<>();
jsonValues.put("auth_token", authToken);
return Response.status(200).entity(jsonValues).build();
```

And it should generate:

{"auth_token":"b88c1d32-2056-4c57-926d-e8213e875b7d"}